# What is the Power shell's equivalent of Python's Regex Search?

Tags: python, powershell

I found PowerShell's regex match but could not find Powershell's equivalent of Python's regex search.

The below is the example in Python.

```
>>> inputstring = "iqn.2007-11.com.storage:srmgrsmisvstvol2-ju7wjffssldf-df-sdf-ewr-v0dd04708bb13b686.000"
>>> match = re.search(r"(\w*-){4}(\w*)", inputstring, re.IGNORECASE)
>>> match.group()
'srmgrsmisvstvol2-ju7wjffssldf-df-sdf-ewr'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! If you could expand a bit on your question it would be very helpful. See [ask] and try to include a [mcve]. Even if you don't have working PowerShell code, since you're comparing to python maybe you can include some example python (for instance I don't use python much so I don't know what you mean by "regex search" but if I saw the code I might be able to figure it out). I'm also going to add the python tag to attract python users who might know both languages.

Answer (score 3):

The PowerShell equivalent of your Python code would look somewhat like this:

```bsh
$inputstring = 'iqn.2007-11.com.storage:srmgrsmisvstvol2-ju7wjffssldf-df-sdf-ewr-v0dd04708bb13b686.000'
if ($inputstring -match '(\w*-){4}(\w*)') {
    $matches[0]
}
```

The `-match` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0#-match) (which is case-insensitive by default) is used for checking a string against a regular expression. If matches are found the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0#matches) `$matches` is populated with those matches. The matches can then be accessed by index: 0 gives the full match, 1 the first captured group, 2 the second captured group, etc.

In addition to the (implicitly case-insensitive) base version (`-match`) PowerShell comparison operators usually have explicit case-sensitive and case-insensitive versions (`-cmatch`, `-imatch`).

```
$inputstring -match '(\w*-){4}(\w*)'   # case-insensitive
$inputstring -imatch '(\w*-){4}(\w*)'  # case-insensitive
$inputstring -cmatch '(\w*-){4}(\w*)'  # case-sensitive
```

You can also enable or disable case-sensitivity via so-called [miscellaneous constructs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#miscellaneous_constructs) inside the regular expression, which take precedence over the operator's case-sensitivity:

```
$inputstring -imatch '(?-i)(\w*-){4}(\w*)'  # case-sensitive
$inputstring -cmatch '(?i)(\w*-){4}(\w*)'   # case-insensitive
```

Comment: Great answer! It might also be helpful to add that the `-match` (and some other operators) can explicitly be made case sensitive or insensitive, with `c` or `i` respectively, as in `-cmatch`, `-imatch`, or the negated forms `-cnotmatch` and `-inotmatch`. In the case of regex, the inline flags in the pattern are also respected and take precedence over the operator, so for example `'ABC' -imatch '(?-i)abc'` is `$false` and `'ABC' -cmatch '(?i)abc'` is `$true`.

Comment: Done. Didn't include the negated operators, though, b/c I think that would veer too much off the topic of this question (this isn't a general discussion of operators after all). It's covered by the documentation, though.